# Can Personalization be done using SQL Server 2000?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, personalization

I am using SQL Server 2000 and ASP.NET 3.5.
I want to implement WebParts in my site. But while running my code it shows me an error :

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

That error seems to be unrelated. I think you need to check your connectionstring?
Explain how you connect to your db and what your connectionstring is.

Did you already manage to setup your database with the necessary tables/views/sp running aspnet_regsql?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx